# Filter and transfer to another sheet "NO CELLS WERE FOUND"

Tags: vba, excel

When i try to run this code without the DATE(which is last month) that is needed to be excluded there is an error says "NO CELLS WERE FOUND" I tried adding "else msgbox" but it is not functioning. Can someone please help me how to add another condition to my codes.
Thanks

```
Sub ExclusionDates()


    Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet

    Set sh = Worksheets("Raw Data") 'set the sheet to filter
    Set ws = Worksheets("Exclusion") 'set the sheet to paste
    ws.Range("AD1", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp)).clearcontents '<--| clear "paste" sheet columns A:L cells from row 1 down to column A last not empty one

'    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With sh '<--| reference your "copy" sheet
        With .Range("AD1", .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its columns A:L cells from row 1 down to column A last not empty cell
                       .AutoFilter field:=10, Criteria1:=xlFilterLastMonth, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic

            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0) '<--| if any cell filtered other than headers (which get always filtered) then copy filtered values to "paste" sheet
            .Resize(.Rows.count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete '

        End If

                End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

'    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What are you expecting to see happen when you try to filter without last month? Also, can we see some sample data? Is a filter actually applied? You are clearing out A:AD then trying to filter it I think.

Comment: I excluded the last month i need to filter it and transfer to another sheet which is "Exclusion". What am i asking is that when the data i tried to run does not have last month i encounter an error saying " no cells were found" i want to use else statement so that whenever there are no data last month there is a messageBox telling that no data was found. I can't get the exact syntax to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use error handling. Place On Error GoTo ErrHand just before line where you expect error to be thrown.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExclusionDates()

    Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet

    Set sh = Worksheets("Raw Data")              'set the sheet to filter
    Set ws = Worksheets("Exclusion")             'set the sheet to paste
    ws.Range("AD1", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).ClearContents '<--| clear "paste" sheet columns A:L cells from row 1 down to column A last not empty one

    '    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With sh                                      '<--| reference your "copy" sheet
        With .Range("AD1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its columns A:L cells from row 1 down to column A last not empty cell
            .AutoFilter field:=10, Criteria1:=xlFilterLastMonth, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic

            On Error GoTo ErrHand:
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0) '<--| if any cell filtered other than headers (which get always filtered) then copy filtered values to "paste" sheet
                .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete '

            End If

        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    '    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Exit Sub

ErrHand:

    If Err.Number = 1004 Then                    'could use 1004 here

        MsgBox "No cells found"
        Err.Clear
    Else
        Debug.Print Err.Description

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: On which field is the (Criteria2:= xlLastyear) ? Is it an And condition on the same field?

Comment: .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=xlFilterLastMonth, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=xlLastyear

Answer (score 2):

I think the flaw is in

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1
```

that would always return True since it'd check how many cells are visible in referenced range, which is some range spanning from columns A to AD, hence always returning at least 30 (the number of columns header)

so you may want to use

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Columns(1)) > 1
```

here's the code with that correct line and the `Else` and some other comment adjusting

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExclusionDates()

    Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet

    Set sh = Worksheets("Raw Data") 'set the sheet to filter
    Set ws = Worksheets("Exclusion") 'set the sheet to paste
    ws.Range("AD1", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp)).ClearContents '<--| clear "paste" sheet columns A:L cells from row 1 down to column A last not empty one


    With sh '<--| reference your "copy" sheet
        With .Range("AD1", .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its columns A:AD cells from row 1 down to column A last not empty cell
            .AutoFilter field:=10, Criteria1:=xlFilterLastMonth, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Columns(1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell on column A filtered other than header (which gets always filtered)
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0) '<--| copy filtered values to "paste" sheet
                .Resize(.Rows.count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete ''<--| delete filtered values rows
            Else
                MsgBox "No Data found"
            End If
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Well spotted there

Comment: @Qharr, well, let's wait for aicirtap's feedback and see if that is the real issue!

Comment: Thanks @QHarr it makes sense now and yes it is working, just want to ask one more i need to add one more criteria to my code. I also need to add a (Criteria2:= xlLastyear) to filter all the data that has last year or past years. I tried adding that syntax but it is not working.

Comment: This is @DisplayName's answer :-) Though I am happy to read :-)

Comment: Sorry @DisplayName i overlooked it. Can you please help me with my another problem? thanks

Comment: i am having an error when i tried this answer, using columns instead of cells is causing me an error in the syntax so i marked @QHarr answer because i think that is what i am looking for. Anyway, thanks again for your help.

Comment: @aicirtap, what does _"using columns instead of cells i"_ mean? In any case that issue wasn't in your question.

Comment: @aicirtap, any feedback?

Comment: When i tried your answer, it is working but when there is no data found instead of prompting the MsgBox there is an error prompting that's why i  marked @QHarr's answer because that is code i needed without prompting the error. Thank you